# Making a variable count down over x amount of time in android studio

Tags: java, android

Bit of a question i dont really know how to formulate. Making an android app in android studio using java and I want to display a double taken from a textview above (the result of a calculation done with user input) instead of the amount of minutes left on the countdown while still using the same amount of time counting it down.

Say for example the User puts in 4 hours and the value from the double is 12, I want 12 to gradually decrease over the course of 4 hours.

Here is the code

```
InsulinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = InsuEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (!text.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                        final int hours = Integer.valueOf(text);
                        final CountDownTimer TotalTid = new CountDownTimer(hours * 3600000, 60000)
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                double TimePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time;
```

The line below is where the issue is. I need this to display insulindose being gradually decreased over x amounts of hours I know i should do insulindose -(insulindose /countdowntime * timepassed) but it doesn't work, just tells me "Operator cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'long'

```
                        AktivInsulinTextView.setText("Aktiv insulin: " + insulindose - ;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        AktivInsulinTextView.setText("Ingen aktiv insulin");
                    }
                }.start();
            }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide the variable declarations. From the error code it looks like you are using text with numbers, bad idea. You need to parse the text first to an long.

Comment: could it be because of the minus at the end of line? AktivInsulinTextView.setText("Aktiv insulin: " + insulindose - ;

Comment: Hello, could you try closing the parenthesis in : AktivInsulinTextView.setText("Aktiv insulin: " + insulindose );?

Answer (score 0):

Because the first thing you pass into the operation is a String (`"Aktiv insulin: "`), java assumes that it should do string concatenation and the `-` operator doesn't make sense in a string concatenation. Simply put your math in parenthesis and it should work:

```
AktivInsulinTextView.setText("Aktiv insulin: " + (insulindose -(insulindose /countdowntime * timepassed)));
```